# da.InsertCursor not adding correct point

Tags: arcpy

I'm iterating a dictionary and inserting rows however, the shape is not inserted correct. All the rows ends up with the same shape.

My code:

```
    fc= r'C:\Connections\c\Osa\OSA@cB.sde\dvdb.Dv.E\Dv.Dv.Info'
    edit = arcpy.da.Editor(r'C:\Connections\c\Osa\OSA@cB.sde')
    IdShapeDict = dict()
    IdShapeDict['54255'] = (562122.9734, 6322034.7203)
    IdShapeDict['52367'] = (529588.5947, 6304689.1642)
    IdShapeDict['40965'] = (5563882.452, 6243252.3302)

    edit.startEditing(False, True)
    edit.startOperation()             

    cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc, ["Ke","SHAPE@XY"]):
        for strId, shape in IdShapeDict.iteritems():
            cursor.insertRow([strId,shape])

    del cursor
    edit.stopOperation()
    edit.stopEditing(True)
```

If a change the code to this:

```
    fc= r'C:\Connections\c\Osa\OSA@cB.sde\dvdb.Dv.E\Dv.Dv.Info'
    edit = arcpy.da.Editor(r'C:\Connections\c\Osa\OSA@cB.sde')
    IdShapeDict = dict()
    IdShapeDict['54255'] = (562122.9734, 6322034.7203)
    IdShapeDict['52367'] = (529588.5947, 6304689.1642)
    IdShapeDict['40965'] = (5563882.452, 6243252.3302)

    edit.startEditing(False, True)
    edit.startOperation()           

    for strId, shape in IdShapeDict.iteritems():           
        with cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc, ["Ke","SHAPE@XY"]):
            cursor.insertRow([strId,shape])

    edit.stopOperation()
    edit.stopEditing(True)
```

It works. But keep creating and deleting cursors must have an impact on performance

To simplify the issue 
This works as expected:

```
IdShapeDict = dict()
IdShapeDict['54255'] = (562122.9734, 6322034.7203)
IdShapeDict['52367'] = (529588.5947, 6304689.1642)
IdShapeDict['40965'] = (5563882.452, 6243252.3302)

edit = arcpy.da.Editor(r'C:\Connections\c\Osa\OSA@cB.sde')
edit.startEditing(False, True)
edit.startOperation()           

for strId, shape in IdShapeDict.iteritems():           
    with cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc, ["Ke","SHAPE@XY"]):
        cursor.insertRow([strId,shape])

edit.stopOperation()
edit.stopEditing(True)
```

But it creates a new cursor for each iteration.

When moving the creation of the cursor out side the for loop all rows ends up with the same shape

```
IdShapeDict = dict()
IdShapeDict['54255'] = (562122.9734, 6322034.7203)
IdShapeDict['52367'] = (529588.5947, 6304689.1642)
IdShapeDict['40965'] = (5563882.452, 6243252.3302)

edit = arcpy.da.Editor(r'C:\Connections\c\Osa\OSA@cB.sde')
edit.startEditing(False, True)
edit.startOperation()           

with cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc, ["Ke","SHAPE@XY"]):
    for strId, shape in IdShapeDict.iteritems(): 
        cursor.insertRow([strId,shape])

 edit.stopOperation()
 edit.stopEditing(True)
```

Comment: Try a tuple instead of a list in cursor.insertRow((strId, shape)).  If that doesn't help, could you post your wrong output -- which shape do they all get?

Comment: Do the IDs come in correctly?

Comment: Your try/except may be masking useful error messages so I think you should remove that when testing and in any code snippet that you present here.

Comment: @JKelly: Tried with tuple instead - but the result is the same - it seems like it uses the shape from the last entry.

Comment: @PhilippNagel: Yes

Comment: @PolyGeo Ive placed a break point  where i print the exception - but i never hit the break point

Comment: @BERA Im using python2 and arcmap. I might be mixing syntaxs Im very new to both Python and GIS. Im creating the dictinary with IdShapeDict = dict()

Comment: Is the edit session necessary? If not try using insertcursor without it.

Comment: There's advice on writing code snippets to get ArcPy help at https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4312/115

Comment: @BERA yes editor is required

Comment: What if you try it using with statements instead of manually starting and stopping edit session? So with arcpy.da.Editor(xxx) as edit and then with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(xxx) as cursor. As outlined on this site: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/editor.htm  Also your code samples are indendet incorrectly - is that just a SE formatting issue?

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code, but it gives a syntax error on the line where the InsertCursor is defined. Are you sure the code actually completed without errors?

To define a cursor using `with` use this syntax:

```
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc, ["Key", "SHAPE@XY"]) as cursor:
    for strId, shape in IdShapeDict.iteritems():
        cursor.insertRow([strId, shape])
```

In short: **with** [define cursor] **as cursor:**

or alternatively:

```
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc, ["Key", "SHAPE@XY"])
for strId, shape in IdShapeDict.iteritems():
    cursor.insertRow([strId, shape])
del cursor
```

Note the absence of the colon at the end of the first line.